# Best approach to split the single column into multiple columns Dataframe PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Actually I'm beginner with PySpark, and I have a CSV file with approximately contains (8 millions) records, I read it by PySpark as df that looks like this:

[image: 20 rows of dataframe]

This column contains values is concatenated string as [longitude  latitude  timestamp, longitude  latitude  timestamp, .....]. Now I want to divide it into three columns which can be as longitude, latitude and timestamp columns separately.

For example : let's assume the first record as '[104.07515 30.72649 1540803847, 104.07515 30.72631 1540803850, 104.07514 30.72605 1540803851, 104.07516 30.72573 1540803854, 104.07513 30.72537 1540803857, 104.0751 30.72499 1540803860, 104.0751 30.72455 1540803863, 104.07506 30.7241 1540803866, 104.07501 30.72363 1540803869, 104.07497 30.72316 1540803872, 104.07489 30.72264 1540803875, 104.07481 30.72211 1540803878, 104.07471 30.72159 1540803881, 104.07461 30.72107 1540803884]'.

The output should be like:

Longitude column:'[104.07515, 104.07515, 104.07514, 104.07516, 104.07513, .......]'.

Latitude column: '[30.72649, 30.72631, 30.72605, 30.72573, 30.72537, 30.72499,......]'.

Timestamp column:'[1540803847, 1540803850, 1540803851, 1540803854,......]'.

I am trying to find the best approach to do that over all dataframe.

Can anyone please suggest if there is any way to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What's the column data type? Is it string or array<string>? Could you do `df.printSchema()`?

Comment: The column data type is string as: Trajectory_GPS: string (nullable = true). Trajectory_GPS='[104.10569 30.68642 1540803110, 104.10569 30.68643 1540803111, 104.10569 30.68644 1540803114, 104.10569 30.68645 1540803117, 104.1057 30.68645 1540803120, 104.10568 30.68647 1540803123, 104.10567 30.68644 1540803126.....]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string by `', '`, then split each item in the resulting array by `' '` using `transform`, and get the longitude, latitude and timestamp from that.

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "split(trim('[]', Trajectory_GPS), ', ') as newcol"
).selectExpr(
    "transform(newcol, x -> split(x, ' ')[0]) as longitude", 
    "transform(newcol, x -> split(x, ' ')[1]) as latitude", 
    "transform(newcol, x -> split(x, ' ')[2]) as timestamp"
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|longitude                                                                                                                                               |latitude                                                                                                                                   |timestamp                                                                                                                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[104.07515, 104.07515, 104.07514, 104.07516, 104.07513, 104.0751, 104.0751, 104.07506, 104.07501, 104.07497, 104.07489, 104.07481, 104.07471, 104.07461]|[30.72649, 30.72631, 30.72605, 30.72573, 30.72537, 30.72499, 30.72455, 30.7241, 30.72363, 30.72316, 30.72264, 30.72211, 30.72159, 30.72107]|[1540803847, 1540803850, 1540803851, 1540803854, 1540803857, 1540803860, 1540803863, 1540803866, 1540803869, 1540803872, 1540803875, 1540803878, 1540803881, 1540803884]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

To get the max/min of longitude/latitude, you can aggregate the dataframe:

```
result = df2.agg(
    F.max(F.array_max('longitude')).alias('max_long'), 
    F.min(F.array_min('longitude')).alias('min_long'), 
    F.max(F.array_max('latitude')).alias('max_lat'), 
    F.min(F.array_min('latitude')).alias('min_lat')
).head().asDict()

print(result)
# {'max_long': '104.07516', 'min_long': '104.07461', 'max_lat': '30.72649', 'min_lat': '30.72107'}
```